# Alphabetic equivalent of PHP is_numeric

Tags: php

I am looking for a function that would be the alphabetic equivalent of is_numeric.  It would return true if there are only letters in the string and false otherwise.  Does a built in function exist in PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want [`ctype_alpha()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php)

Comment: How is that better than `^\p{Alphabetic}+$`? It looks seriously worse.

Comment: Sorry, why exactly does it look worse?

Answer (score 1):

If you're strictly looking for the opposite of `is_numeric()`, wouldn't `!is_numeric()` do the job for you? Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question. `!is_numeric("ab12") === true`. He wants to check if a string contains _only_ letters.

Answer (score 0):

I would have used preg_match. But that's because I'd never heard of `ctype_alpha()`.

```
if(!preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z]/", $teststring)) {
    echo "There are only letters in this string";
} else {
    echo "There are non-letters in this string";
}
```

Comment: If you have special needs, like only letters + commas and spaces, then a regexp is your best choise :)

Comment: I love/hate it when I'm typing up an answer, and I load in new answers only to see one much better then the one I was writing.

Comment: Don’t use `[a-zA-Z]` for only letters!  Use `\pL`. The real alphabetic property is even better: `\p{Alphabetic}`.  [Here’s why.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955086/sort-upper-case-just-before-lowercase-key-values-from-a-hash/4958634#4958634)

Answer (score 0):

`!is_numeric((float)$variableToBeChecked);`

also

`preg_match('#^[a-z]+$#i',$variableToBeChecked); // for one or more letter character`