# how to check if the inputted data is string in php

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alphabetic equivalent of PHP is_numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323105/alphabetic-equivalent-of-php-is-numeric)

If you check if the data is a number, we use is_numeric:

```
if(!isset($_POST['rnum'])||trim($_POST['rnum'])==""){echo "Error:Enter Room Number!";     
  echo '<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">';
  }else if(!is_numeric(trim($_POST['rnum']))){echo "Error: Enter A Numeric Value!";
  echo '<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">';
die();
  }
```

How about checking if it is string?or expecting that the inputted data are just letters

Comment: Has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323105/alphabetic-equivalent-of-php-is-numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using regex like:

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i',$input_to_be_tested))
 echo 'Has only letters';
else
 echo 'Has non-letters';
```

If you wan to allow spaces in the input you can try:

```
/[\sa-z]+/i
```

Answer (score 0):

DO you only want alphabetic characters? You could use a regular expression to match against `[a-zA-Z]+`, but that would only get letters of the alphabet. Are other characters allowed or not?